# Monaco code editor custom line number for the second editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I am using monaco Code editor in my web page for IDE.

I am using react for my web application

I need to use part of code readOnly and remaining as editable. Unfortunately i could not find the lineRange readOnly option in `monaco` editor.
Hence i chose to put 2 monaco editor in the same page.

```
this.state.DEFAULT_CODE.map((item, key) => {return(                                                                 
    <MonacoEditor key={key}                                                                        
     height='400'                                                         
     className="codemirror1"
     language="C"
      options={options}                                                                       
       value={item.value}
      editorDidMount={(editor, monaco) => {
      this.editor = editor;
      editor.addCommand(monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.KEY_C, () 
       => null);
     }}
    onChange={(value) => {
     this.setState({
       DEFAULT_CODE: value,
     });
    }}
   />
)
```

Now i want the second editors line numbers to be started from the end of lines of first editor..
IS it possible....
if so can anyone help me....

Comment: Could you please explain the problem and desired outcome more clearly?  Even better, please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Thank you

Comment: Thank you for asking..... ... I want to change the starting line number of the monaco editor manually.... I know there is an option in ACE editor as `editor.setOption("firstLineNumber", 10);` ... Is there any option in monaco editor .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lineNumbers` option. Here is an example that make line numbering zero based:

```js
options = {
  lineNumbers: num => num - 1,
  lineNumbersMinChars: 2,
  glyphMargin: false,
};
```

Here is another example that maps numbers to roman numerals:

```js
const useRomanNums = (num) => {
    const map = [ 'O', 'I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX', 'X'];
    return (num < map.length) ? map[num] : num;
}

const options = {
  lineNumbers: useRomanNums
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use `lineNumbers` option.

```
options = {
  lineNumbers: 5,
  lineNumbersMinChars: 6,
  glyphMargin: false,
};
```